# Using Python to pull files/(kml's) from multiple URLs

Tags: javascript, python, beautifulsoup, gis, google-earth

I'm a beginner with python and was trying to automate a process which involves going to a site :http://www.wildcad.net/WildCADWeb.asp and clicking every single dispatch center, for example: http://www.wildcad.net/WCAZ-ADC.htm  , from there loading a kml. I noticed that each page follows a similar format so I thought I could use a select all function. I wrote my code as...

```html
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

urls = ('http://www.wildcad.net/WCAZ-ADC.htm', 'http://www.wildcad.net/WCALAIC.htm',
       'http://www.wildcad.net/WCAR-AOC.htm','http://www.wildcad.net/WCAZ-ADC.htm'
       'http://www.wildcad.net/WCAZ-FDC.htm', 'http://www.wildcad.net/WCAZ-PDC.htm'
       'http://www.wildcad.net/WCAZ-PHC.htm', 'http://www.wildcad.net/WCAZ-SDC.htm'
       'http://www.wildcad.net/WCAZ-TDC.htm', 'http://www.wildcad.net/WCAZ-WDC.htm')


 result = requests.get(urls)
    doc = BeautifulSoup(result.text, 'html.parser')
    print(doc.prettify())
    for i in enumerate(soup.findAll('a')):
        _KML = urls + link.get('href')
        if _KML.endswith('.kml'):
            urls.append(_KML)

    open(_KML)
```

However it doesn't seem to pull the files and I keep getting an error message on line '65' Any direction or example of how to remedy this will be very much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Working code. Please just run the code.

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'http://www.wildcad.net/WildCADWeb.asp'

driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())
driver.maximize_window()
time.sleep(2)
driver.get(url)
time.sleep(5)

soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, "html.parser")

for link in soup.select('table[align="center"] tbody tr td a')[1:]:
    url=link.get('href')
    #print(url)
    if url.endswith('.kml'):
        kml_url = url
        print(kml_url)
```

Output:

```
http://www.wildcad.net/WAearth.kml
```